# Why is punishment allowed in Islam?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation, punishment

To anyone reading I am not trying to say this in a hateful way or manner I'm just eager to know.There is capital punishment and other forms of punishment. Why do these even exist because they are so violent and Islam most definitely is a religion of peace. Stoning etc are very violent and when punishing someone for it, it basically takes their life away so they never get a chance to turn back for repentance. Can somebody explain why it is allowes? Also there were narrations where the prophet (pbuh) said stone people or throw them off high buildings. This is really violent and does not show peace. I'm not trying to say in a hateful way I'm just trying to learn that what is the point of punishment and why the need for it because it is not for repentance and the only thing you get out of it is a dead person. Why not just teach them to repent and change ways instead of killing them?

Comment: You need to do this so it stops other people doing these crimes, look how common in the western society to have adultery, if these people were stoned to death for this no one would do it. The Jews have and eye for eye law, the Christians turn the other cheek, but we Muslims do what it takes to stop it happing again.

Comment: Yes I learnt about justice and deterrence but sometimes it can be for something such as being sexually attracted to the same sex. This I find a bit unusual because aren't their some genetic relations that cause attraction towards the same gender. If a person is attracted to the same gender but doesn't commit any illegal acts (illegal in the case of religion) isn't this unfair? Btw I'm not gay if you thought I were.

Comment: in islam you can be gay and Muslim, you just cannot practice homosexuality. There is no punishment in Islamic law or the hearafter for being merely attracted to someone. But if a Gay restrains his soul from lust and purifies himself then Allah will definitely reward him in the hereafter  79:40. And Allah loves those who purify themselves for Him and they indeed are the successful ones 91:9.

Comment: Allah's command will keep those who fear Him from committing crimes. But what about those who don't fear Him? There are many such people driven by only desire. For such people, capital punishment is a means to deter them from doing such crimes. For a believer, the command of Allah is enough but for a disbeliever it bears no meaning in his heart, hence capital punishment is enforced.

Comment: whether you are homosexual or heterosexual, a person that follows his desired is doomed in the hereafter. All four imams do not agree on capital punishment for gays that practice homosexuality, some say this should only be done if there is adultery involved, other wise they are just punished (i.e. same as hetero). Also in the Quran: If two men among you are guilty of lewdness, punish them both. If they repent and amend, Leave them alone; for God is Oft-returning, Most Merciful.(4:16), thus no-where is capital punishment mentioned in fact here contrary to you post they are able to repent

Answer (score 1):

Legal punishment is ordained, not just allowed, in Islam. The reason it is a part of Islam is because Allah says so, and He knows better what measures are effective and what is in our benefit.

> ولكم في القصاص حياة يا أولي الألباب لعلكم تتقون
>
> And there is for you in legal retribution [saving of] life, O you [people] of understanding, that you may become righteous.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:179](http://quran.com/2/179)</sup>

> وعسى أن تكرهوا شيئا وهو خير لكم وعسى أن تحبوا شيئا وهو شر لكم والله يعلم وأنتم لا تعلمون
>
> But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:216](http://quran.com/2/216)</sup>

People who are given capital punishments **do** get a chance for repentance, they are not magically, instantly executed upon doing the deed.